# Riverpod StateNotifier not working with hover logic

Tags: flutter, dart, state, riverpod

I am trying to use Riverpod and it's StateNotifier in order to control my navbar. Below is my code:

StateNotifier File

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final navigationControllerRP =
    StateNotifierProvider<NavigationControllerRP, NavigationControllerElement>(
        (ref) => NavigationControllerRP());

class NavigationControllerRP
    extends StateNotifier<NavigationControllerElement> {
  NavigationControllerRP() : super(NavigationControllerElement("Home", ""));

  void changeActiveTo(String item) {
    state = NavigationControllerElement(item, "");
    state = state;
  }

  void changeHoverTo(String item) {
    if (item != state.activeItem) {
      state = NavigationControllerElement(state.activeItem, item);
      state = state;
    }
  }

  bool isActive(String item) {
    return state.activeItem == item;
  }

  bool isHover(String item) {
    return state.hoverItem == item;
  }
}

class NavigationControllerElement {
  var activeItem = "";
  var hoverItem = "";

  NavigationControllerElement(this.activeItem, this.hoverItem);
}
```

Usage file for the notifier

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:platform/constants/controllers.dart';
import 'package:platform/constants/style.dart';
import 'package:platform/controllers/navigation.dart';
import 'package:platform/widgets/custom_text.dart';

class NavBarElement extends ConsumerWidget {
  /// Creates a navbar element which can be displayed at the top of the page.
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String route;

  NavBarElement({
    required this.title,
    required this.url,
    required this.route,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return InkWell(
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Consumer(
            builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  CustomText(
                    text: this.title,
                    size: 16,
                    color: ref
                            .watch(navigationControllerRP.notifier)
                            .isActive(this.title)
                        ? Color.fromRGBO(70, 70, 70, 1)
                        : Colors.grey,
                    weight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 7,
                  ),
                  ref
                          .watch(navigationControllerRP.notifier)
                          .isActive(this.title)
                      ? Container(width: 50, height: 1, color: Colors.black)
                      : Container(),
                  ref.watch(navigationControllerRP.notifier).isHover(this.title)
                      ? Container(width: 50, height: 1, color: Colors.red)
                      : Container(),
                ],
              );
            },
          )),
      onTap: () {
        ref.watch(navigationControllerRP.notifier).changeActiveTo(this.title);

        // navigationController.changeActiveTo(this.route);
        Get.toNamed(route);
      },
      onHover: (value) {
        value
            ? ref
                .watch(navigationControllerRP.notifier)
                .changeHoverTo(this.title)
            : ref.watch(navigationControllerRP.notifier).changeHoverTo("none");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My activeItem logic works correctly but the hoverItem logic does not seem to work. Everytime I hover over a navbar element, it seems to be updating the state i.e. setting the hoverItem for my NavigationControllerElement object but it is not reflected in the UI. Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using StateNotifier is incorrect. The `StateNotifier` should not have anything listenable outside of `state`

In particular, what you did wrong is adding getters/methods on the `StateNotifier` made to be used by the UI:

```dart
class Model{...}

class MyNotifier extends StateNotifier<Model> {
  ...

  bool isActive(Item item) => state.activeItem == item; // DON'T DO THIS
}
```

then used as:

```dart
final isActive: ref.watch(myProvider.notifier).isActive(myItem);
```

Instead, this should be on your state class:

```dart
class Model{
  bool isActive(Item item) => activeItem == item;
}

class MyNotifier extends StateNotifier<Model> {
}
```

then used as:

```dart
final isActive: ref.watch(myProvider).isActive(myItem);
```

Comment: So if I wanted to apply this to the hoverItem, I would simply add a function `bool isActive(Item item) => hoverItem == item`, correct?